# To find current day lies in given range

Tags: javascript, json

Im getting the following JSON

```
[ {
    "endOfWeek": "Friday",
    "id": "HDAY-19842",
    "holidayDate": "08/18/17 00:00:00",
    "startOfWeek": "Monday"
} ]
```

---

```
var x = getGmtTime();
```

How to find x lies in between "startOfWeek" and "endOfWeek" or not ??

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. You just need to know if `x` is a day of the week between Monday and Friday?

Comment: What is `x` here? A `Date`?  A number?  Representing what?

Comment: x is date value like this "Fri Aug 18 2017 06:14:05 GMT+0530 (IST)"

Comment: So it is a string and the first ”word” is always an English abbreviation of a weekday? That information is somewhat crucial for answering the question. :-) What have you tried so far, and where is the concrete problem with that?

Answer (score 2):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) is a great library to use for this.  You could easily do the following:

```
var x = moment(getGmtTime());
if (x.isBefore(arr[0].endOfWeek) && x.isAfter(arr[0].startOfWeek))
  // do something
```

This is assuming the array from your example is stored in variable named arr.

**Edit**

Per comment on this answer, moment also supports working with days of the week.  It's a very versatile library.  You could do the following:

```
var x = moment(getGmtTime());
if (x.isAfter(moment().day('Monday')))
  // Do something
```

See [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/).

Comment: I don't think that to add an external library just for this would be a good idea

Comment: @rakwaht dates are extemely complicated.  Formatting, time zones, date math are all a headache, and built-in JavaScript date functionality leaves a lot to be desired.  I use momentjs in every project that deals with dates, just because it makes the whole process more manageable.

Comment: I now that momen.js is quite good and I agree that if the project deals a lot with dates it would be fair to include it. However in this case, if this is the only case I would not include a huge external library just for this small task

Comment: The above code doesn't work since moment compares only date string like x.isAfter('2000-01-01') . But in my case i need to compare x.isAfter('Monday')

Comment: Expanded answer to show use case which fits this scenario.

Comment: That just sets the day but leaves the current time as is. You need to set that to zero to cover the whole Monday.  So it's more like `moment().day('Monday').hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0)`.

Comment: Or shorter `moment().day('Monday').startOf('day')`.